# how to get all the event listeners of every element using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get the event listeners of all the elements on the DOM (without need the user to fire any event).

I am using chrome extensions, but i didn't found any way to this even with the chrome.devtools api.

what i did find, is the following console api function

```
getEventListeners(document);
```

but it's only running on the console, i can't run it on the actual code.

Any ideas?

I don't have any relevant code to show here, the documentation of the function getEventListeners() says that it's running only on the console, but might be a way to do it with chrome extensions, but it don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: [DOMDebugger.getEventListeners](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMDebugger/#method-getEventListeners)?

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure how to use it.
When i use on the console or on the actual code it's return an exception
"Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMDebugger is not defined"

Comment: Find a demo extension that uses chrome.debugger API and see how it invokes *remote debugging protocol*. Then figure out how to invoke this particular method.